# Regular expression : How to match a specific word with having spaces and with an additional letter in the starting or ending?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Im trying to do something fairly simple with regular expression in php

What i want to do is matching words from a string no matter wherever that same character is. If its at the beginning of the string there is no whitespace required before - if its at the end, don't search for whitespace either.

Example :

```
String : "test.chris@rocketmail.com"
Word Search: "christest"
```

I want the output to be matched the word search from the string

I tried below pattern but its still not working 100% as expected

```
[^\s]+christest
```

I have tried here :

> https://regex101.com/r/0BGZmY/1

Comment: How can `christest` match `test.chris` logically?

Comment: @nice_dev, Word search is basically name of user and search string is email so want to match and check if the name which I am getting is correct with email string or not.
So Chris is firstname and test is lastname, here the email is test.chris, so can you help me in that.

Comment: so if `christ` is first name and `test` is the last name, you can search them individually. Because the email could also be like `test.something.christ@gmail.com`

Comment: "*[Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the existence of the two words `chris` and `test` anywhere in the string you can use a regexp with two lookaheads:

```
/(?=.*chris)(?=.*test).*/g
```

See here: https://regex101.com/r/milVww/1

If the existence of *one* of the target words is enough for you you can do:

```
/(?=.*(chris|test)).*/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/l8JZrH/1

Comment: okay, can not be searched in single word like christest in email and pattern gives boolean true as email is having some letters which is there in pattern?